# form onsubmit doesn't work end changing value of input

Tags: javascript, php, forms, onsubmit

I'm making a form to change the password.
I ask for the current password and then there are two fields to put the new password.
I have two problems:
First: I need to check if the two fields of the new password are equal.I used onsubmit to check that.If they are the same, submit.If not it should show a message saying something.The problem is that it doesn't display.This is the code:

```
function checkform(){
    var pass=myForm.pass.value;
    var new=myForm.new.value;
    var new=myForm.new2.value;
    if(new!=new2){
       document.getElementById("message").style.display='block';
       document.getElementById("pass").value=" ";
       document.getElementById("new").value=" ";
       document.getElementById("new2").value=" ";
       return false;
     }else{
         return true;
     } 
}
```

When I insert diferent new passwords it still submits, but if I delete that  document.getElementById it doesn't submit.
Second problem: I have a php page (not using frameworks, just php) that is a class.When I want to acess a function of that class all I need to do is

```
include("class.php");
$my = new the_class(); $response= $my->check();`
```

The check() function retrives the password, so then I can check if  the value from the field pass is the same as the $response.But how can I put this on the function checkform()? It doesn't work this way.

Comment: Might be a copy and paste problem but you are setting the same variable `new` to both your `new` and `new2` values.

Comment: Also, `new` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript so you shouldn't be naming a variable that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted use this link to solve your problem

Comment: I had already seen that post.If i put alert() instead of that document.getelementbyid it works.What i don't understand it's why if i put the document.getelementbyid it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Don't take the variable name as new its a keyword it is reserved for creating an instance, so better take some other name to the variable and you may get what you're looking for.

Comment: I used new as an example, that not the name...I'm sorry, it was my mistake put it in here that way

Comment: Mar10Bel----- May i know  y ur not using JQuery, to achieve this

Comment: What i posted is what i'm using.Didn't understand the question

Comment: Mar10Bel----  I got your question, am just asking you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **You Try below code**   

   function checkform(){
        var pass=myForm.pass.value;
        var new=document.getElementById("new").value();
        var new=document.getElementById("new2").value();
        if(new!=new2){
        document.getElementById("message").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("pass").value=" ";
        document.getElementById("new").value=" ";
        document.getElementById("new2").value=" ";
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't stop the submit...This is the html code of the onsubmit: <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" action="page.php" method="POST" onsubmit="checkform()">